# I'm getting a DoesNotExist error with django rest auth password reset

Tags: django, django-rest-auth

I've installed and configured django-rest-auth, everything seems to be working properly except the `/rest-auth/password/reset/` endpoint.

When I do a POST to it, passing the email via JSON, a 500 - DoesNotExist error is returned:

`DoesNotExist at /rest-auth/password/reset/
Site matching query does not exist.
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://.../rest-auth/password/reset/
Django Version: 1.9.5
Exception Type: DoesNotExist
Exception Value: Site matching query does not exist.
Exception Location: /home/.../.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py in get, line 387
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.10`

What could be causing this?

Comment: Did you tried this?: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/sites/#enabling-the-sites-framework

Comment: @mariodev Yes it worked! Thank you! Please add as answer so I can mark it as the solution :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

django-allauth (used internally by DRA) looks for the domain name by searching for `Site` object.

Please follow these steps to set up sites framework:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/sites/#enabling-the-sites-framework